# Directions API returning different route that the maps webpage/app

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am currently going through the directions and static map APIs and trying to display a map for each route individually. So I got the routes from the directions API but the results are inefficient (to put it mildly).

For example:
For the directions API call with the following params:
alternatives=true

departure_time=now

origin=MF+Vruksha%2C+121%2C+Mount-Medavakkam+Main+Road%2C+Nanmangalam%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600117

destination=Mast+Kalandar%2C+6%2F1%2C+By+Pass+Road%2C+Near+Murugan+Kalyana+Mandapam%2C+Anand+Garden%2C+Gangai+Nagar%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600042

The last route (overview_polyline) in the request when plotted on a static map gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s1lP.png) (please note the useless cycle at the bottom of the image), whereas the more logical route would be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocP1Y.png) as given by maps.google.com.
Please note that I have removed the API key from my request and it's not an enterprise key.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, can you plese state why you did it, so I can prevent it in the future?

Comment: Your problem is with the input to the directions service.  Those are "places" not postal addresses.  If I get the coordinates from the places api, then get directions, I get a very different result ([the second alternative looks a lot like the google maps result you posted](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?alternatives=yes&addr1=MF+Vruksha%2C+121%2C+Mount-Medavakkam+Main+Road%2C+Nanmangalam%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600117&addr2=Mast+Kalandar%2C+6%2F1%2C+By+Pass+Road%2C+Near+Murugan+Kalyana+Mandapam%2C+Anand+Garden%2C+Gangai+Nagar%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600042&place=1&place=2))

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. Asking the places API for the coordinates worked. Looks like the directions API took a different coordinate which was on the other side of the road and hence the different results. Though I still doubt why it had to induce a cycle. A simple u-turn should have sufficed. Anyway, can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the input to the directions service. Those are "places" not postal addresses. If I get the coordinates from the places api, then get directions, I get a very different result ([the second alternative looks a lot like the google maps result you posted](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?alternatives=yes&addr1=MF+Vruksha%2C+121%2C+Mount-Medavakkam+Main+Road%2C+Nanmangalam%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600117&addr2=Mast+Kalandar%2C+6%2F1%2C+By+Pass+Road%2C+Near+Murugan+Kalyana+Mandapam%2C+Anand+Garden%2C+Gangai+Nagar%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600042&place=1&place=2))

[image: output when use places API for locations]